# Magento 2.3 static Block to replace subcategories in navigation

Tags: static-block, navigation, sub-categories

I am attempting to add a block in place of the subcategory in the main navigation or site navigation. I don't want to use a bloated extension, just minimal code. I am using a **blank** custom theme I made. In the photo below you will see the "Women" link has a block shown during mouse over dropdown instead of the subcategories. I will code the block with the rest of the mega menu in it per say.

I'm trying to make most of the links on the site navigation this way, 7 for now. The mobile view should be normal subcategory view.

**i seen the post sort of like mine. It's not the same.**

I GREATLY APPRECIATE the help. if you will please provide details if you can. folder structure / locations and where code gos as i may not be as well versed as the average bear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into this file,

```
Magento\app\design\frontend\<Your Theme>\<sub folders>\Magento_Theme\templates\html\topmenu.phtml
```

In my case it is

```
Magento\app\design\frontend\Solwin\freego\Magento_Theme\templates\html\topmenu.phtml
```

**Look for variable $_menu**

The sub categories will be retrived from this code block

```
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>
```

If you want to override you can change the below HTML.

```
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?php if ($showhomelink) { ?>
            <li class="level0 level-top <?php if ($ishome) { ?> active <?php } ?>">
                <a class="level-top" href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by plugin after method

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**
Now create **app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/CategoryCustomItemPlugin.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CategoryCustomItemPlugin
{

public function afterGetHtml(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topmenu, $html)
{
$customurl= $topmenu->getUrl('yoururl'); //here you can set link
$CurrentUrl = $topmenu->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);
if (strpos($CurrentUrl,'yoururl') !== false) {
$html .= "
";
} else {
$html .= "
";
}
$html .= "" . __("yoururl") . "";
$html .= "
";
return $html;
}
}
```

This way you can add your static-block code as an HTML.